# Some images stored in s3 are not loading in Safari

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, safari

So essentially I have a React app with a Node backend and I'm storing 650 or so images in an s3 bucket and everything works perfectly fine on Chrome, but in Safari about 10 images do not load with this message being logged in the console :
[My screen when loading s3 Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIFus.png)

As you can see it says there is an error loading the resource, and I have tried updating the metadata of the image in the actual bucket, but nothing seems to be working. Has anyone ever experienced something like this? Please let me know any suggestions!

Answer (score -1):

Please check image mime type. In case it doesn't match with extension, it doesn't open in browser